# How to check if a cell belongs to a dynamic name range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a few dynamic name-ranges and I want to check in VBA if a cell (ex the active cell) belongs to one of them.

For example, I have created the namerange

```
nameTest1=OFFSET(A1;0;0;COUNT(A1:A12))
```

And I want to check if the active cell is within this range.

I have found various ways to do that, but not on dynamic name-ranges.

Is there a way to do it?

Regards

Thanasis

Comment: Use the `Intersect` method? Not sure why it would be any different than any other range - what ways have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to do the test, nameTest1 is a named range.

```
If Not Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("nameTest1")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "activecell is in range nameTest1"
Else
    MsgBox "activecell is not in range nameTest1"
End If
```

Comment: Yes, this works. 

Thanks.

Is there a way to check if a cell belongs to a dynamic name range, and if yes, which is the name of this range?

Comment: `For Each nr In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If Not Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, Range(nr.Name)) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "activecell intersect with " & nr.Name
        End If
    Next`

Answer (score 0):

To determine to which named range the active cell belongs to, try this

```
For Each nr In ActiveWorkbook.Names 
  If Not Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, Range(nr.Name)) Is Nothing Then 
   MsgBox "activecell intersect with " & nr.Name 
 End If 
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked a bit the solution from h2so4:

```
For Each nr In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, Range(nr.Name)) Is Nothing Then
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            MsgBox "activecell intersect with " & nr.Name
        End If
    End If
    Err.Clear
Next
```

Thanks for your help!